# Oracle 11g database copy

Tags: oracle, copy

I got database oracle 11g on my localhost on laptop. I would like to copy it to run on other PC (windows) for some tests. How can I do that?

Comment: with DataPump(expdp and impdp command line utilities)

Comment: does your laptop run windows, too? depending on your source database there are multiple options from simple copy, export/import, rman duplicate. Please provide more information.

Comment: @jmk got laptop on windows 10, and i would like to install oracle 11g on pc and just import the same database from some file.

Comment: If you want a 1:1 copy of your database, follow Mguerra‘s answer given below. If you need to modify the user or things like that, a manual import with a parameter file might be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've installed the Database Instance onto your other PC:

Use SQL Developer's "Database Copy" to copy straight from one to the other, or "Database Export" to simply export the source database into file(s).
They're available in the "Tools" menu.

Both instances should be running if you choose "Database Copy."

If you choose "Database Export," you can choose to have it all go to one or the other.

Beware of disk space and wallet issues, and ensure your other instance's environment is ready to take the new structure/files.